# How to push Spark dataframe to Sql Server table when set_identity is off?

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

So, I have a table in Sql Server with Id column and it's an identity column. The problem I am facing is that when I try to push my data frame into it, it complains that identity_insert is set to 'off'. Now, I am explicitly setting it to 'on' using jdbc but since this is a session variable on sql server side, it gets turned back to 'off' by the time the dataframe push command is hit, because both are different sessions for sql server.

Is there a way to turn if 'on' and push dataframe in the same session?

Some code - 
Sql Server table

```
create table dbo.testtable
(
 [Id] int identity,
 [Name] varchar(100), 
 [Address] varchar(100),
 [ExtraColumn] int, 
 [Age] int
)
```

My data frame -

```
case class TestClass(Id: Int, Name: String, Address: String, ExtraColumn: 
Int, Age: Int)

val seqClass = Seq(TestClass(1, "kv", "riata", 2, 30),
                 TestClass(2, "xyz", "xyz's place", 2, 31),
                 TestClass(3, "abc", "abc's place", 2, 32))

val sparkSession = createSparkSession //creating through some method
val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(seqClass)
JDBCUtils.setIdentityInsertOn(conn, JDBC.SQL_SERVER.TYPE, 
"testdb1.dbo.testtable", None)  //my method to turn on identity_insert

//code to push data frame to sql server 
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").jdbc(jdbcUrl,"testdb1.dbo.testtable",
getConnectionProperties(username,password, dbType))

//getConnectionProperties is my own method that provides connection 
//properties for jdbc.
```

Note that the above works all fine if I remove the Id column from data frame. So the code overall works, just that I need be able to maintain Id on the dataframe and push it to testtable. Why I cannot simply use identity generation from testtable? Because the above code is part of much complex workflow and I need to generate Id columns like above in the data frame.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Able to resolve this issue after reaching out to Vaibhav offline who had already implemented the solution. I am posting the same here for others to use in future.

Make a local copy of SaveTable() and dependent functions from JDBCUtils.java at below location-
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala

Update the SavePartition function to insert below lines of code -

```
if(Identity_Insert_Off) {
  val sql = "set IDENTITY_INSERT " + table + " ON";
  val statement = conn.createStatement()
  statement.execute(sql)
}
```

before line 640 while loop.

```
while (iterator.hasNext) {...}
```

Update if condition based on scenario (i am using this code only for SqlServer so only checking for Identity Insert Flag which gets passed to the function)

Below query can be used to check Identity is On or Off for a particular table-

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('<TableName>'), 'TableHasIdentity');
```

Comment: Although this works, this is probably not the correct way for spark to handle this. There should be an option available in the api to support this. The core answer for someone looking at this later is that in the bean class leave out id column (which is pointed out as well in the question)

Comment: But here, how can we inject the local SaveTable() method in spark flow? as currently JdbcUtils.scala is being referred to by spark SQL flow.